# Change DIV tag content dynamically with JSP code

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I'll describe how the thing works now and then what I wish to achieve:

I've got a basic HTML page which has a textbox and a **Send** button. When I type some string and click the button this request gets to a Servlet. The servlet does something and then redirects the req&resp to a jsp file (`getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("myJSP.jsp").forward(req, resp);`)

So basically, when someone types something in the textbox and clicks on the **Send** button he gets a new page which was generated by the ***myJSP.jsp*** file.

Is there any way that instead getting a complete new file I want the result that the ***myJSP.jsp*** generates to be shown in the same main page, let's say under the textbox (in a DIV tag?).

How can I achieve such a behavior?

Comment: this is basically just asking how to do ajax... way too broad. Maybe read some tutorials and if you get stuck come back with a specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing jquery $.ajax() function, first download jquery.js and keep it to your project folder and locate it. follow as below:

```
<head>
 <script src="../resources/jquery.js"></script> <script src="../resources/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <input type="text"><input class="button" type="button" value="Click">
<div></div>
<script>
    $(".button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
              url: "ajax.html",
              cache: false
            }).done(function( html ) {
              $("div").append(html);
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do an asynchronous request with javascript so that the page does not reload for the user. The server has to return a response you can then append to the page with javascript.

This technique is called [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). A popular tool (besides tons of other ways) for doing ajax requests is the `ajax()`  function of the JQuery javascript library ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))